# Check if environmental configs are existent

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel in one of my project and recently pulled all sensitive configuration from into .env-files which are of course not commited to the repo.

I'm working with 3 "machines": dev, staging and production.

Now to not forget to set needed API keys, database configuration etc. I put a env.sample into the repo in which all keys which have to be modified according to the environment are present.

Now my question is: since the environment-specific .env-files are not present in my repo, how could I implement a method which checks if the environment-specific config is present to reduce possible human errors?

Would something along these lines be a good idea?

```
if (!file_exists('.env.' . App::environment() . '.php))
    return false;
```

Thanks for your input!

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 4.2.

Comment: So these environment specific files are a custom solution? (in other words you load them yourself?)

Comment: No. Laravel does that: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#environment-configuration

Comment: Oh. Okay nevermind then... I don't think this is a bad idea but you might want to consider checking for the actual values you need from the file instead of just the file. So before you use the API key you check for it's existence and if it's not there, throw an exception.

Comment: Could you tell to what file you added this code ?